# Efflorescence on chimney bricks inside the house

Tags: brick, chimney

I have recently whitewashed my brick chimney. It’s irrelevant to the problem but white background color makes efflorescence more noticeable.  After a month of whitewashing, my chimney (January in MA, which is the coldest month) developed yellow efflorescence.
My chimney or roof does not seem to be leaking, or is it? I see the efflorescence on random bricks.

**Questions I have:**

- Do I have a water leak somewhere? I have a chimney cap, it’s a two floor house, and the chimney is on the first floor. I have three furnaces heating the house and exhaust goes into chimney. When I touch the bricks on cold days, there is moisture. There is no one at home during the day so I keep it at 57F, and at night 63-68F.
- Is it possible that condensation is forming on the bricks which is causing efflorescence?
- Finally, do I need to do anything about it? Is it going to deteriorate my chimney, do I need to call a professional, or just ignore it and keep cleaning it. Is there a way of preventing condensation and stopping efflorescence?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the RH of your house?  The mortar looks wet with liquid moisture signs.  You could easily have water seaping into your chimney from the roof and running down the inside of the chimney.  You might also just have moisture from the furnace exhaust condensing somewhere on the inside cold surface of the chimney and running back down.

Comment: You've got way too many questions in one here. Please pick the most important one and edit it down to that one, then ask other questions for the other issues. Maybe start with the "do I need to do anything about it", because if the answer to that is "no", the rest are moot points.

Comment: Relative Humidity in this room is around 40-43%